# Marshalling D3D11Device and D3D11DeviceContext objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, marshalling, direct3d11

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The ID3D11DeviceContext methods (except for those that exist on
>   ID3D11DeviceChild) are not free-threaded, that is, they require single
>   threading. Only one thread may safely be calling any of its methods
>   (Draw, Copy, Map, etc.) at a time.

I was wondering if I can make COM do the `ID3D11DeviceContext` synchronization for me.

Let's say I do this (in simplified code):

```
CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED );
// Create D3D11Device
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> pD3D11DeviceContext;
pD3D11Device->GetImmediateContext(&pD3D11DeviceContext);
```

Then I either marshall it:

```
IStream* pStreamD3D11DeviceContext = NULL;
CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknownD3D11DeviceContext;
pD3D11DeviceContext->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pUnknownD3D11DeviceContext));
::CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream( __uuidof(ID3D11DeviceContext), pUnknownD3D11DeviceContext, &pStreamD3D11DeviceContext );
```

Or us a GIT table:

```
CComPtr<IGlobalInterfaceTable> pIGlobalInterfaceTable;
::CoCreateInstance( CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGlobalInterfaceTable, (void **)&pIGlobalInterfaceTable );
CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknownD3D11DeviceContext;
DWORD    dwCookieD3D11DeviceContext = 0;
pD3D11DeviceContext->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pUnknownD3D11DeviceContext));
pIGlobalInterfaceTable->RegisterInterfaceInGlobal( pUnknownD3D11DeviceContext, __uuidof(ID3D11DeviceContext), &dwCookieD3D11DeviceContext );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.
`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` returns `REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG` (`0x80040155, Interface not registered`) and `pStreamD3D11DeviceContext` remains NULL.

GIT method goes one step further. I get the cookie, but when I try to use it on another MTA thread, the GetInterfaceFromGlobal returns E_INVALIDARG.

```
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> pD3D11DeviceContext;
hresult = pIGlobalInterfaceTable->GetInterfaceFromGlobal( dwCookieD3D11DeviceContext, __uuidof(ID3D11DeviceContext), (void**)&pD3D11DeviceContext );
```

The params for `GetInterfaceFromGlobal` seem okay, I tested getting the pointer back on the original thread and it worked.

The `D3D11Device` and `D3D11DeviceContext` appear to be unmarshallable. Obviously I have neither proxy DLL nor a typelib for the d3d11.

Am I missing anything?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. There is no marshaling support for these interfaces. You will have to manage without.